# Dependency Injection with Jersey

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, jersey

If I am using Jersey 1.12, and I have multiple resource classes, and they all need to access some shared context, what's the best way to inject a dependency, whether it be in the constructor for the resource class, or into the handler method? Do I need to use an external DI library, or does Jersey have something built-in?

i.e. maybe the resource for Foos looks like this:

```
package com.example.resource;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/some/api/path/foo")
public class FooResource
{
    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String getFoo(@QueryParam("id") String id)
    {
        Foo foo = /* get a Foo from some shared context based on id */
        /* Process foo into a String */
    }
}
```

and for Bars:

```
package com.example.resource;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/some/api/path/bar")
public class BarResource
{
    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String getBar(@QueryParam("id") String id)
    {
        Bar bar = /* get a Bar from some shared context based on id */
        /* Process bar into a String */
    }
}
```

Comment: http://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/migration.html#mig-server-inject-custom-objects

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49221066/942671

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ended up using Google Guice, which is a lightweight DI framework that integrates well with Jersey. Here's what I had to do:

First, I added dependencies in the pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-guice</artifactId>
        <version>1.12</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I wanted a DAO implemented as a singleton with an interface:

```
public interface MySingletonDao
{
    // ... methods go here ...
}
```

and a concrete implementation:

```
@Singleton
public class ConcreteMySingletonDao implements MySingletonDao
{
    // ... methods go here ...
}
```

Decorated the resource classes like so:

```
@Path("/some/path")
@RequestScoped
public class MyResource
{
    private final MySingletonDao mySingletonDao;

    @Inject
    public MyResource(MySingletonDao mySingletonDao)
    {
        this.mySingletonDao = mySingletonDao;
    }

    @POST
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String post() throws Exception
    {
            // ... implementation goes here ...
    }
}
```

Created a class that will do the bindings:

```
public class GuiceConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener
{
    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector()
    {
        return Guice.createInjector(new JerseyServletModule()
        {
            @Override
            protected void configureServlets()
            {
                bind(MyResource.class);
                bind(AnotherResource.class);
                bind(MySingletonDao.class).to(ConcreteMySingletonDao.class);
                serve("/*").with(GuiceContainer.class);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I used Jetty instead of Glassfish to actually act as the server. In my functional test, that looks something like:

```
private void startServer() throws Exception
{
    this.server = new Server(8080);
    ServletContextHandler root =
        new ServletContextHandler(server, "/", ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);

    root.addEventListener(new GuiceConfig());
    root.addFilter(GuiceFilter.class, "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));
    root.addServlet(EmptyServlet.class, "/*");

    this.server.start();
}
```

The `EmptyServlet` comes from Sunny Gleason's sample code given out as an answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3296467 -- I originally had

```
root.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(new PackagesResourceConfig("com.example.resource"))), "/*");
```

instead of the line

```
root.addServlet(EmptyServlet.class, "/*");
```

But that caused Jersey to try and perform the dependency injection instead of Guice, which caused runtime errors.

Comment: This more Inversion of Control than Dependency Injection. This sound fussy but this distinction has opened a world to me.

Answer (score 3):

you can use SingletonTypeInjectableProvider: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.12/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/inject/SingletonTypeInjectableProvider.html

sample:

```
ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new DefaultResourceConfig();
resourceConfig.getSingletons().add(
        new SingletonTypeInjectableProvider<Context, SingletonType>(
               SingletonType.class, new SingletonType()) {});{code}
```

or you can create SingletonTypeInjectableProvider descendant, annotate it with @Provider add it as a class. The you can inject provided instance wherever you need and where standard Jersey injection kicks in.

Comment: Here's an answer how to do it with the `@Provider` annotation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10899513/473775.

Answer (score 1):

There is a jersey-spring project that supports Spring dependency injection.  Replace your jersey ServletContainer with a SpringServlet, add a ContextLoaderListener to your web.xml and you can inject beans into your components.  Here's a pretty decent walkthrough of the setup

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/

EDIT

Here's an idea that doesn't require adding any dependencies.  Create your own ServletContextListener that adds your objects to the ServletContext.  Then inject the ServletContext into your Resources

```
public class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener
{

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event)
    {
        ServletContext context = event.getServletContext();
        context.setAttribute(Foo.class.getName(), new FooImpl());
    }

}
```

Then in your Resource

```
@Path("blah")
public class MyResource 
{
   private Foo foo;

   public MyResource(@Context ServletContext context)
   {
      foo = (Foo) context.getAttribute(Foo.class.getName());
   } 
}
```

Comment: I count a total of 4 Spring dependencies that I'd have to add. That seems rather heavy-handed.

Comment: Added another suggestion for you

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use an external library unless you want to.  It's well documented that getting CDI to work correctly with Jersey is currently a pain.  However I can speak from experience that it can be done having done it myself.  It's been awhile since I jumped through those hoops but I seem to recall we had to make our Resources Stateless EJB's to get it to work.  There could have been other steps I took but I don't recall those now.

When Jersey 2.0 comes out this should get a whole lot easier as they'll be switching over to using the Core CDI implementation instead of their own.  See this bug for more info:

http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-517